# Prepare sting for url containing slavic chars (Đ -> Dj and đ -: dj)

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace, iconv

I want to translate strings containing latin slavic chars like "š, đ. č, ć" to a friendly url strings. Problem is with letter đ and Đ.

```
protected function NameForUrl($name) {
    // Replace chars Đ, đ

    $string = $name;
    $pattern = '/([đ])+/';
    $replacement = 'dj';
    $clean = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $clean);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", '-', $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

The problem in my code is that when preg_replace changes the 'đ' to 'dj' than iconv removes the 'j' from 'dj', and i donćt want it to be just "d".
What encoding should be used for this to work, or how can i do it without iconv, as there are more stings like š,ć, č...?

Comment: [For me it works.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e22dc2bcf6ccab70ed76ac90596eb388220e785e)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I must check then if problem lies somewhere else...

Comment: Problem may be in hosting's iconv configuration or you don't have everything in UTF-8 (file, page, ...)